# How to use the shipping gem in ruby on rails 3 for USPS API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, usps

I've found the `shipping` gem for ruby here http://shipping.rubyforge.org/ searching on google for some information on integrating  `USPS` API on a Ruby on rails application but when I install the gem and add it to my `Gemfile` as i run the `bundle install` whenever a try to run my application or a rake taks i get the following error:

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shipping-1.6.0/lib/shipping/ups.rb:109: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shipping-1.6.0/lib/shipping/ups.rb:437: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shipping-1.6.0/lib/shipping.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/myusername/railsapps/dbh4/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require'
    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have removed now the gem from my `Gemfile` and my application is up and running but, I don't even know if this gem works for `Rails 3` or even if this gem works for `USPS` API.

Any help on this? I need to integrate USPS Web Tools with my Ruby on Rails 3 Application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shipping gem is old and will not work with rails 3  (last release was in [October 2009](http://rubygems.org/gems/shipping))

Try https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping

It supports:

- UPS
- USPS
- FedEx
- Canada Post
- New Zealand Post

Comment: Should i get this on the `vendors/plugin` directory or install this as a plugin with `rails plugin install git://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping.git` ?

Comment: You can just install with gem install active_shipping or adding gem 'active_shipping' to your Gemfile.